# What is this medal that LBJ is wearing?

Tags: political-history, identification, president

This photo shows President Lyndon Johnson wearing a medal that I can't ID:

[image: LBJ wearing some medal]
<sup>(LBJ, Westmoreland, and Air Force One. ¿In New Orleans?)</sup>

[LBJ supposedly won the *Silver Star* in WW2](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2001/jul/06/internationaleducationnews.humanities), but that looks different:

[image: WW2 Silver Star]

So, **what is that medal on LBJ's lapel?**

---

**Update:**
The original [image is apparently an AP photo](http://www.apimages.com/metadata/Index/Watchf-Associated-Press-Domestic-News-Louisiana-/a3fccd093940485ab358ca6b38bc62b9/9/0).  And AP says:

> ...Army Chief of Staff Westmoreland had just arrived and will address the American Legion Convention Tuesday evening on Sept. 10, 1968 in New Orleans,Los Angeles. **No explanation for (the) medal on Johnson's lapel.** ( AP Photo)

<sup>(Emphasis added.)</sup>

Comment: The silver star lapel pin can be seen above the unidentified medal on LBJ's lapel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the medal of the American Legion:

[image: American Legion]

According to the notes that accompany the [picture on the AP website](http://www.apimages.com/metadata/Index/Watchf-Associated-Press-Domestic-News-Louisiana-/a3fccd093940485ab358ca6b38bc62b9/9/0), the photograph was taken:

> ... after President Johnson's address to the national convention of the American Legion Tuesday afternoon,September 10, 1968.

JBJ was famously a member of the American Legion, and was [awarded the Legion’s Distinguished Service Medal](https://www.legion.org/moment-in-time/212475/how-many-us-presidents-have-received-legion%E2%80%99s-distinguished-service-medal) in 1968.

---

[Similar lapel badges](https://emblem.legion.org/Badges-Year-Bars/products/156/) are still available to members of the American Legion.

---

The silver star lapel pin:

[image: Silver Star lapel pin]

can be seen above the Legion medal on LBJ's lapel